# Converting WrappedArray to string in DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` like the following:

```
+---+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------+
| _1|                              _2| _3|                              _4| _5|                              _6|
+---+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------+
|  2|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|  1|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|  0|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|
|  3|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|  1|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|  0|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|
|  3|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|  2|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|  1|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|
|  3|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|  2|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|  0|WrappedArray(String,String,St...|
+---+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------+
```

I want to convert the `WrappedArray`s to strings and have the following output:

```
+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2| _3|                  _4| _5|                  _6|
+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+
|  2| String,String,St...|  1| String,String,St...|  0| String,String,St...|
|  3| String,String,St...|  1| String,String,St...|  0| String,String,St...|
|  3| String,String,St...|  2| String,String,St...|  1| String,String,St...|
|  3| String,String,St...|  2| String,String,St...|  0| String,String,St...|
+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+
```

How to do the convert in Spark, using Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat_ws` function to create a string from an array as

```
val finalDf = df.withColumn("_2", concat_ws(",", $"_2"))
  .withColumn("_4", concat_ws(",", $"_4"))
  .withColumn("_6", concat_ws(",", $"_6"))
```

Hope this helps!